# Mermaid js Latest version without module

Tags: javascript, module, mermaid

I am using mermaid JS to build flowdiagrams on the fly using the latest version `10.1.0` gives us options to style the content but at the same time are not letting use callback on node click.

10.1.0 has to be used as script module:

```
<script type="module">
  // clicks not working as part of this code, supposed to invoke `navigateToChild`
  import mermaid from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10.1.0/+esm";
  var textColName = "Desc";
  xls = groupBy(xls, levels);
  mermaid.initialize({
    flowchart: {
      useMaxWidth: true,
      htmlLabels: true,
    },
    securityLevel: "loose",
  });
  refreshGraph(processWorkflowData(xls, null));

  function refreshGraph(data) {
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementsByClassName("mermaid")[0].removeAttribute("data-processed");
    document.getElementsByClassName("mermaid")[0].innerHTML = data;
    function navigateToChild(e) {
        console.log("innnn");
        if (e && e != "") {
            refreshGraph(processWorkflowData(xls, e));
        }
    }
    mermaid.contentLoaded();
  }
</script>
```

Older version can be directly used as scripts works fine:

```
<script>
  var textColName = "Desc";
  xls = groupBy(xls, levels);
  mermaid.initialize({
    flowchart: {
      useMaxWidth: true,
      htmlLabels: true,
    },
    securityLevel: "loose",
  });
  function onLoadFunction() {
    refreshGraph(processWorkflowData(xls, null));
  }
  function refreshGraph(data) {
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("mermaid")[0]
      .removeAttribute("data-processed");
    document.getElementsByClassName("mermaid")[0].innerHTML = data;

    window.navigateToChild = function (e) {
      refreshGraph(processWorkflowData(xls, e));
    };
    mermaid.contentLoaded();
   
  }
</script>
```

Any help on how to resolve the issue? Either by continuing to use esm import or by directly embedding raw js file.

NOTE: Raw js for 10.1.0 doesnt seems to be available